ID a movie featuring humanoid robots roaming in cities
Around ten years ago, I watched this movie. I remember this movie is quite touching. This is what I remember:
Year : 2000's. Not newer than 2010 and not older than 90's. 
Display: Not much CGI. It's in color and in English.
Plot: A man and his son (which are humanoid robots) are trying to go to someone to find a clue about a whereabouts of a place. They were hunted down by authorities. They travel on foot, by flying cars, and by chopper. Finally, they find the place in the destroyed city. After some scene, they separate and the boy rides the chopper and flies away.

are the boy and the man robots?

yes. I'll add that in my question.

Yeah, sure sounds like A.I.. The (android) man, played by Jude Law, wasn't the father, they were just two down-on-their luck A.I.s. Do you remember a talking teddy bear?

I'm pretty sure that you are referring to the movie A.I. Artificial Intelligence. You can check it on IMDB. It has all the reference you mentioned except for the fact that the two robots are not related and the movie is from year 2001, which matches your time frame.  
This probably is the scene you are describing.

Sadly realizing that he is not unique, a disheartened David attempts to commit suicide by falling from a ledge into the ocean, but Joe rescues him with their stolen amphibicopter. David tells Joe he saw the Blue Fairy underwater and wants to go down to her. At that moment, Joe is captured by the authorities with the use of an electromagnet, but he sets the amphibicopter on submerge.

Here is the trailer. Hope this is what you were looking for.




A good movie up until he jumps in the water. Fade to black, done, cut, the end. After that, a colossal insult to Natural Intelligence. People walked out, exasperated sighs all over the theater, much nashing of teeth

@Yorik, you do realize that it's not the end of the movie right? There is a scene that takes place after the scene that you described.

I found that final scene was expendable too, it unnecessarily extends the movie, giving it a new closure and a "happy" ending that it didn't really need.

@ashan: oh, I realize that. reread what I wrote.

Ah, got what you meant!
